# Why java socket.io emit is fail

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i'm creating android application with Socket.io and node.js server.

My js server:

```
 var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
});

var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:,
    port:,
    user:,
    password:,
    database:
});

var resultconnection = "";

db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) {
    resultconnection = err;
    }
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
   console.log('Connected!');

    socket.on("createaccount", function(data){
        console.log('Create account executed.');
        if(resultconnection != ""){
            db.query("INSERT INTO USER (USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, BIRTHDATE) VALUES('"+data["username"]+"', SHA1('"+data["password"]+"'), '"+data["email"]+"', "+data["birthdate"]+"')");
            resultconnection = "OK";
        }
        socket.emit('response', {"response": resultconnection});
    });


});

server.listen(8080);
```

Android client(java):

```
try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8080");
            socket.on("response", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    try {
                        result = obj.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
            socket.connect();
            JSONObject createUser = new JSONObject();
            try {
                createUser.put("username", username);
                createUser.put("password", password);
                createUser.put("email", email);
                createUser.put("birthdate", datanasc);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            socket.emit("createaccount", "");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        }
```

Console.log("Connected") is running but when I run the socket.emit("createaccount") the client does not run on the server.

Comment: Are you testing App on emulator or real device?

Answer (score 0):

I think the server IP you gave in the client code is not correct. It is trying to connect to the localhost of your Android device while your server is running on some other remote system.
Try changing the server IP in the following snippet(ideally this should be something other than localhost):

```
try {
        socket = IO.socket("<server_IP:server_PORT");
        socket.on("response", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];
                try {
                    result = obj.getString("message");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        socket.connect();
        JSONObject createUser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            createUser.put("username", username);
            createUser.put("password", password);
            createUser.put("email", email);
            createUser.put("birthdate", datanasc);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.emit("createaccount", "");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are significant structural problems with how your server is designed:

1. You're trying to save `resultconnection` in a module global.  That means you can only ever have one socket.io client connection that will work properly.  The second connection will see the `resultconnection` from the previous client connection.  There's just no way this is a proper way to do things.  It could possibly work if you never ever had more than one client connect to your server - not just one client at a time, but one client all time.
2. The way you handle the async database operation in the createaccount message handler is just wrong.  You are trying to `.emit()` the `resultconnection` back to the client before it has been set.
3. Your error handling for the `db.connect()` call does not seem correct.  When you can't connect to the database you need to take some action, not just set a variable as such and proceed on as if nothing is wrong.  Even that variable you set is being used wrong later.  You're checking to see if you had an error on the connect and if you did, then you're trying to do a database operation.  Besides just a messed up design, this logic is even backwards.

To think about how to fix the first issue, you need to explain what you're trying to do with this statement:

```
 if(resultconnection != ""){
```

because that will need to be done a different way.  You can't just save global state in your server and expect that to represent the state of any incoming connection.

How to fix the second issue will depend upon what is done for the first issue.

How to fix the third issue involves some design decisions about what to do with your server when you can't connect to the database (shut-down, retry, log, etc...).

Comment: I understood the part of the variable really is wrong .

But the console.log I put on this event before this check, it is not executed.

I discovered that the connection is made and lost , how do I keep connected client ?

Comment: @MillerDominguês - I don't understand what you're asking in your last comment.

Comment: in client I run socket.connect(), and the server print console.log( "connected!"), but when using socket.emit("createaccount") , the server does not print the console.log('Create account executed.'), which this before IF.

Comment: @MillerDominguês - That just sounds like your first problem before the above issues is that your client isn't connecting with your server.  I don't know Android so I can't help you with the Android code.